# How can I judge the object if is exists in the templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

In the template:

```
    <h4>
        {% if data.wine_one %}
            {{ data.wine_one.title }}
        {% elif data.news_one  %}
            {{ data.news_one.title }}
        {% endif %}
    </h4>
```

I promise the `data.wine_one` is exists, because in the `views.py` I have print out it.

But in the templates it do not shows up the `data.wine_one.title`, and I use the `data.wine_one != None` can not judge it too.

---

**EDIT**

In the `views.py`:

```
def getData():

    banner = models.Banner.objects.filter(fk_info=1)
    info = models.Info.objects.all().first()
    aboutus = models.AboutUs.objects.all().first()
    winery = models.Winery.objects.all()[:3]
    winery_consult = models.WineryConsult.objects.all()[:4]

    data = {

        'banner': banner,
        'info': info,
        'aboutus': aboutus,
        'winery': winery,
        'winery_consult': winery_consult,
    }

    return data    

def productdetails(request, nid):

    data = getData()

    wine_one = models.Winery.objects.filter(id=nid).first()

    data['wine_one'] = wine_one

    print (data['wine_one'].title)  # there ouput the "gaoliangjiu"

    return render(request, 'article_list_content.html', data)
```

Comment: Does it show `data.news_one.title` instead? Or nothing at all?

Comment: @Hamish shows nothing.

Comment: Can you show us what the relevant function in `views.py` does?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `data.wine_one` correctly from your `views.py` to the template ?

Comment: And the relevant models.

Comment: @Hamish Have edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood how the template context works.

There's no element called `data` in the template; that's just the local variable you're using in the view to build up the context. In the template, you just reference the keys of that object directly. So it should be:

```
    {% if wine_one %}
        {{ wine_one.title }}
    {% elif news_one %}
        {{ news_one.title }}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I should pass the `{'data':data}`